# Using userids to generate encryption key

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I would like to encrypt some personal data stored in a database accessed by teachers (data related to students, such as their names, special needs status, grades etc). I've used `open_ssl_encrypt` in a very basic way before, but my level of understanding is pretty entry-level.

What I think I would like to do (and do correct me if this is bad), is to use a different encryption key for each user, so that they can't access each other's data. I would generate this key by in some way combining a master key (known only to me) with the user's id.

Thus, the encryption keys are not themselves stored in the database, so a database hack couldn't decrypt the data. A hacker would have to have access to my source code to obtain the master key, as well as having the knowledge that (and how) this is then combined with user's id.

Is this a common solution? Is it sensible? Is it secure?

Thank you.

Comment: I suppose I want to protect student privacy in the event that all my database was hacked and leaked. A single encryption key would work in that case. The reason for multiple keys would be to prevent one user being able to see records for other users, but since the MySQL selects filtering for userid, that shouldn't be possible anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mike's answer would add too much complexity for something that should be invisible to users. I don't want users to have to remember/store a key in order to view their data; the fact that the data is encrypted should be irrelevant to their flow through my app.

The solution I went with in the end was to have one common encryption key, stored on the server, away from public_html. Each user also has their own encryption key, stored in the MySQL database. These keys are XORed to create a key that encrypts or decrypts their data.

It is completely invisible to users, which is good. To breach this defence, a hacker would have to access both the server and the MySQL database and combine the keys correctly. The data I'm protecting isn't *that* sensitive (not credit cards or anything financially valuable).

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing some sort of master key in the code, you're really not securing anything because this essentially makes the data available in plain text on the server. Here's how I would approach it.

1. To be used with asymmetric encryption, a separate public and private key for each staff member that will need access to some personal data will be generated. The public keys are stored on the server. They will need to keep their private keys private.
2. When a document is added to the server, a new symmetric key (e.g. AES) is generated and the document is encrypted with this. Each document should have its own symmetric encryption key. For each staff member that will need access to that file the symmetric key is then encrypted with their public key. The encrypted versions of the public key are then stored on the server along with the encrypted document and the plain text document and symmetric key are discarded.
3. When a staff member needs access to a file, they provide their private key. The private key decrypts the symmetric key and the symmetric key decrypts the file.
4. When updating the file, it will need to be re-encrypted using the same symmetric key.

[[Source](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/71915/3499)]

The only caveat to this is if many people need access to a single document, it could take a while to encrypt the symmetric key using all of their public keys. However you seem to indicate that each document would need to be accessed by at most two people, so it shouldn't be much of a problem.